# Configure Java 8 Exceptions list for all users on a computer?

Tags: security, java

I need to add several sites to the Java exceptions site list in Java 8. The problem is that Java's security settings are done on a per user basis and not on a per system basis.

This means that when I remote into a computer to alter the setting it only does so for my account and not other users on the computer.

How can I change the exception site list for all users on a computer without having to change it for every single user on the computer?

Answer (score 1):

Option 3
If you create a java config file called `deployment.config` under the following path:

```
WINDIR%\SUN\JAVA\Deployment
```

JAVA will consider the information added at that path as global, to ALL users of a single PC. This might help a lot in scenarios of deploying JAVA exception sites, for example, to all users of a network.

Actually, there are three files that are very importante on doing such config deploy:

- deployment.config
- deployment.properties
- exception.sites

For more information regarding how to set this type of configuration properly, please read the article:
http://www.adminarsenal.com/admin-arsenal-blog/managing-javas-control-panel-exception-site-list

Answer (score 0):

#### How can I change the exception site list for all users on a computer?

**Option 1**

Modify the `exception.sites` file for each user.

The location of this file depends on the operating system.

On Windows the location is:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security\exception.sites
```

**Option 2**

Use a [Deployment Configuration File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/properties.html)

> A default deployment.properties file, located in a User's profile is
>   where the control panel and exception site list are usually managed.
>   However, this is only on a per-user basis. This is not too helpful to
>   a sys admin needing to manage multiple computers or maintain standard
>   settings across their enterprise.
>
> That's where creating a deployment.config file comes in. Deploying
>   this file out to your computers allows you to reference your very own
>   deployment.properties file and exception.sites file.

This article goes on to explain how to a create and use a `deployment.config` file.

Source [Manage Java's Control Panel and Exception Site List](http://www.adminarsenal.com/admin-arsenal-blog/manage-javas-control-panel-and-exception-site-list)

---

#### References

- [Deployment Configuration File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/properties.html) - This topic describes system and user properties that can be set to configure the deployment process.
- [Manage Java's Control Panel and Exception Site List](http://www.adminarsenal.com/admin-arsenal-blog/manage-javas-control-panel-and-exception-site-list)